# Making the size of two fields in comment form the same programmatically

Tags: theming, forms

in my node comment form I have a 'your name' field and an 'email' field for users to fill out. They are different in length and like them both to be length '30'. How can I do this with hook_form_comment_form_alter?

I've tried this, with no success (in template.php):

```
$form['field_email']['#size'] = 30;
$form['author']['#size'] = 30;
```

I've tried just changing the size of the field for the email field in the content type comments manage fields area but it does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the core comment form the 'author' element is an array of form elements:

```
  $form['author']['name']['#size'] = 30;
  $form['author']['mail']['#size'] = 30;
```

Comment: Just in addition, for @Sage to know the proper array structure. The Devel module's dsm() function could help with that too. Just for future needs.

Comment: That worked after all; thanks guys! @Shawn Conn thanks as always.